# return empty dropdown list without JQUERY (in controller)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-select

Necessary when loading a web application to return empty Dropdown List `@Html.DropDownList("gorod", (SelectList)ViewBag.listCity, "--Выберите город--")`, because it has more than 20 000 rows in the database!!

Необходимо при загрузке веб-приложения возвращать пустой дропдаун лист `@Html.DropDownList("gorod", (SelectList)ViewBag.listCity, "--Выберите город--")`

view

```
/* DDL джейсон*/
        $('#gorod').hide();
        $("#oblast").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCitys", "Registration")',
                data: { thisValue: $("#oblast option:selected").val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    var ddl = $('#gorod');
                    ddl.empty();
                    $.each(data, function (value, i) {
                        ddl.append(
                                $('<option/>', {
                                    value: i.Value,
                                    html: i.Text
                                }));
                        $('#gorod').show();
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
    /*Конец DDL джейсон*/



@Html.DropDownList("oblast", (SelectList)ViewBag.listOblast, "--Выберите область--")
@Html.DropDownList("gorod", (SelectList)ViewBag.listCity, "--Выберите город--")
```

controller

```
ViewBag.listOblast = new SelectList(dm.getOblasti().ToList(), "kod", "name_ru");
ViewBag.listCity = new SelectList(dm.getCitys().ToList(), "kod_obl", "name_ru");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write plain HTML

```
<select name="oblast">
 <option>--Выберите область--</option>
</select>
```

Simple.

Comment: how NEXT i can LOAD info width json in this select?

Comment: the Javascript in your question looks like it should work. So only as you put it in jQuery docment ready.

Comment: i used the partial view <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#oblast').change(function () {
                if ($('#oblast option:selected').val() != "")
                { $('#test').load("goroda", { param1: $('#oblast option:selected').val() }) }
            });
        </script><div id="test"></div>

Comment: great - don't forget to make my answer as correct if it helped you